# Run script on VPS start

Tags: command-line, server, bash, permissions, scripts

I have a VPS, and I want to execute a script on the VPS starts. The script is located in `/home/user_name/unicorn_start.sh` with the following content:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec /etc/init.d/unicorn_appname start
```

As a root, I gave the permission to the script, so it can be executed: `chmod +x unicorn_start.sh`

Then, in `/etc/rc.local`:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.
/home/user_name/unicorn_start.sh || exit 1

exit 0
```

But after I reboot the server, the script seems not to be executed.

Also, I tried to add it to `crontab`, by doing `crongtab -e`:

```
@reboot /home/user_name/unicorn_start.sh
```

But it didn't help either.

What am I doing wrong? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: What Ubuntu version is running on the VPS? it seems perverse to run something from rc.local if it's already an init.d script

Comment: It is Ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0):

So @Alex, you are doing a good bit wrong here... you said that you gave the "permission" to the script to be executable when in reality that means you made the script executable. You can find the actual permissions of the file by doing `stat --format "%a" file_name` but you were right, you need the script to be executable to run. Anyways, when you ran `stat --format "%a" file_name` this on your file, were the permissions `755`?. If they weren't perform `chmod 755 file_name`, this should fix the issue(if you are still using crontab).

Comment: It has 755 permission, I just forgot to inform about it.

Comment: So, could we get a status update? @AlexZakruzhetskyi

Comment: Still doesn't work

Comment: Can you check if crontab is running by `service cron status`?

Comment: `service cron status` tells me that cron is running. May be smth. wrong with the script? However, running it manually: `./unicorn_start.sh` in `/home/user_name` gives me the desired result.

Comment: @AlexZakruzhetskyi . I am running out of ideas here. Maybe you made a mistake in your script, have you tried executing by typing `./script_name`?